# Why Prophet Mahummad Spill Water on the Child's Face and Also Prophet Also Says to Not to Waste Water

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, sahih-muslim

I was Reading An Hadith from [sunnah.com:77](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:77)
There This was Written,

> When I was a boy of five, I remember, the Prophet (ﷺ) took water from a bucket (used for getting water out of a well) with his mouth and threw it on my face.
>
> حَدَّثَنِي مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ يُوسُفَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو مُسْهِرٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ حَرْبٍ، حَدَّثَنِي الزُّبَيْدِيُّ، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، عَنْ مَحْمُودِ بْنِ الرَّبِيعِ، قَالَ عَقَلْتُ مِنَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم مَجَّةً مَجَّهَا فِي وَجْهِي وَأَنَا ابْنُ خَمْسِ سِنِينَ مِنْ دَلْوٍ‏.‏

and there is also an hadith talks about water preservation and saving water!
I am Not Understanding these Two Scenarios also,
Why in the First Case, Prophet Spill the Water from his mouth to a child's face.
Give me the Answers.

Comment: Which hadith on saving water do you have in mind? Conserving water does not mean that you can't use it. The prophet did it either as playful gesture or for tabarruk, both of which are valid purposes.

Comment: @UmH How do you know it, it is playful gesture and I still did not understand your reason of water, Can you please simplify it. Thanks a lot for your Answer.

Comment: It certainly makes huge difference whether you "waste" a gulp of water or some liters or gallons of it. And as stated by UmH you mentioned water preservation without giving evidence about it.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I think Wasting is wasting

Comment: That's your personal view.